# Getting Information about e-mail Attachments with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to receive information about attachments in the Mail App. So far I am able to receive Data from the e-mail that is selected. But I would additionally like to receive information about the attachments.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of selectedMessages
    set theMailbox to mailbox of theMessage
    set mailAddresses to email addresses of account of theMailbox
    return theAttachment in theMessage's mail attachments
end tell
```

The Script works if I use `return mailAdresses` but I cannot get Information about the attachment. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, the return value contains the data

- `theMessage`
- `theMailbox`
- `mailAddresses`
- name und mime type of all attachments as a list

of each message of all selected messages

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    set mailBoxData to {}
    repeat with aMessage in selectedMessages
        set theMailbox to mailbox of aMessage
        set mailAddresses to email addresses of account of theMailbox

        set attachmentData to {}
        repeat with anAttachment in (get mail attachments of aMessage)
            tell anAttachment to set end of attachmentData to {name, MIME type}
        end repeat
        set end of mailBoxData to {theMessage, theMailbox, mailAddresses, attachmentData}
    end repeat
    return mailBoxData
end tell
```